# Canonical projection-Naming

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Why is it named like that? seriously what does canonical even mean? I tried to look it up but I only found church related usages of the word.

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_form

Comment: The church meaning (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblical_canon) is oldest, yes. Its meaning comes close to "standard", "God-given"; κανών means measuring stick, so a standard by which other things are judged.